# Better way to iterate over several foreach loops together and add it to a datagridview C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get use 3 foreach loops to get single values from powershell and add them in a row. My code is as follows:

```
string listDomains = "Get-MsolDomain";
string getLicenseInfo = "Get-MsolAccountSku";
string domainsInfo = executeCommand.runAzurePowerShellModule(listDomains, "Name");
string availableLicensesTypes = executeCommand.runAzurePowerShellModule(getLicenseInfo, "AccountSkuId");
string totalLicenses = executeCommand.runAzurePowerShellModule(getLicenseInfo, "ActiveUnits");
string consumedLicenses = executeCommand.runAzurePowerShellModule(getLicenseInfo, "ConsumedUnits");     
List<string> licenseTypeArray = new List<string>();
List<string> totalLicenseArray = new List<string>();
List<string> consumedLicenseArray = new List<string>();

foreach (string s in Regex.Split(availableLicensesTypes, "\n"))
{
    licenseTypeArray.Add(s);
}
foreach (string v in Regex.Split(totalLicenses, "\n"))
{
    totalLicenseArray.Add(v);
}
foreach (string t in Regex.Split(consumedLicenses, "\n"))
{
    consumedLicenseArray.Add(t);
}
```

I was wondering if this can even be done. I was looking at concatenating the three lists and then splitting them but I could not think of anything after concatenating the strings. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I want to add these values to a datagridview with 3 columns after that.

Comment: how is the data organized? is it even guaranteed that all three arrays will have the same number of rows? are they ordered so that the first licence type entry corresponds to the first total and consumed, so you would have columns like " type | total | consumed "?

Comment: I don't understand (1) what you're asking here, or (2) why you are not simply calling `ToList`. Why is your program not simply `var licenseTypeArray = Regex.Split(availableLicensesTypes, "\n").ToList();` and so on? Can you clarify the question?

Comment: Are you saying that you have three lists of strings, and you would like one list where each element of that list is the concatenation of the three corresponding items in the other three lists?  For that use `Zip`.

Comment: Basically, the runAzurePowerShellModule method gets a column of the powershell output like "AccountSkuId", "ActiveUnits", "ConsumedUnits". Each column has several values. I need to show this output in a datagridview. So i basically have to get individual string values from these powershell output columns by using the foreach loops. Then, I have to put these values in a datagridview. Datagridview.addrow(AccountSkuId, ActiveUnits, ConsumedUnits) foreach value from the 3 foreach loops.

Comment: Sorry I hope this explains it. Yes, the number of rows for each foreach loop will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete code to handle this. I have tested the code and it is working fine. Just copy this code in any aspx page to test. It displays sample data in a gridview after doing the data transformation you're looking for.

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Web;
        using System.Web.UI;
        using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

       namespace SampleTest1
       {
            public partial class _Default : Page
            {
                 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
                 {
                     List<string> licenseTypeArray = new List<string>() { "Type 1", "Type 2", "Type 3" };
                     List<string> totalLicenseArray = new List<string>() { "100", "200", "300" };
                     List<string> consumedLicenseArray = new List<string>() { "50", "100", "150" };

                     //A generic list of the new entity class that wraps the three properties (columns)
                     List<LicenseInfo> licensesList = new List<LicenseInfo>();

                 //concat zip the three lists with a comma-separated for each entry    in the new list with this pattern ("License Type, Total Count, Consumed Count"). 
                 //Example("Entrprise License,200,50")
                 List<string> licensesConcatenatedList = licenseTypeArray.Zip(totalLicenseArray.Zip(consumedLicenseArray,
            (x, y) => x + "," + y),
            (x1, y1) => x1 + "," + y1).ToList();


                 licensesConcatenatedList.ForEach(t => licensesList.Add(new LicenseInfo
                 {
                     LicenseType = t.Split(new char[] { ',' })[0],
                     TotalLicenesesCount = int.Parse(t.Split(new char[] { ',' })[1]),
                     ConsumedLicensesCount = int.Parse(t.Split(new char[] { ',' })[2])
                 }));

                GridView1.DataSource = licensesList;
                GridView1.DataBind();
       }
     }

        class LicenseInfo
        {
            public string LicenseType { get; set; }
            public int TotalLicenesesCount { get; set; }
            public int ConsumedLicensesCount { get; set; }
        }
     }
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi, I have finally got it working. There was a blank entry from the powershell output and this was giving the error. Thank you very much for this code. It is working perfect.

Comment: Very glad to help and to know it is working now. Please mark it as an answer if you found this helpful.

Answer (score 4):

It is difficult to understand what you're asking here. I think you are saying that you have three sequences:

```
    var s1 = "a b c".Split(' ');
    var s2 = "d e f".Split(' ');
    var s3 = "g h i".Split(' ');
```

And you wish to concatenate them "vertically".

You need a zip-concat operation:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ZipConcat(IEnumerable<string> xs, IEnumerable<string> ys)
{
    return xs.Zip(ys, (x, y) => x + y);
}
```

And now your problem is easy:

```
    var s4 = ZipConcat(ZipConcat(s1, s2), s3);
    foreach(var s in s4)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Produces:

```
adg
beh
cfi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `AddRange` instead of iterating over the items:

```
licenseTypeArray.AddRange(Regex.Split(availableLicensesTypes, "\n"));
totalLicenseArray.AddRange(Regex.Split(totalLicenses, "\n"));
consumedLicenseArray.AddRange(Regex.Split(consumedLicenses, "\n"));
```

I hope this is what you meant with easier way. If not please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to avoid using three for loops and shorten the lines of code

```
        licenseTypeArray = Regex.Split(availableLicensesTypes, "\n").ToList();
        totalLicenseArray = Regex.Split(totalLicenses, "\n").ToList();
        consumedLicenseArray = Regex.Split(consumedLicenses, "\n").ToList();
```

For displaying this data in a GridView or so, I think you will need just two columns, the first column to list all the license names, the second column to show if it is available or consumed (Boolean value [true or false]).

OK, fine. Please try the following code. First of all define a new entity class like the following.

```
        public class LicenseInfo
        {
           public string LicenseType { get; set; }
           public int TotalLicenesesCount { get; set; }
           public int ConsumedLicensesCount { get; set; }
        }
```

Then use the following code:

```
        List<string>licenseTypeArray = Regex.Split(availableLicensesTypes, "\n").ToList();
        List<string> totalLicenseArray = Regex.Split(totalLicenses, "\n").ToList();
        List<string> consumedLicenseArray = Regex.Split(consumedLicenses, "\n").ToList();

        //A generic list of the new entity class that wraps the three properties (columns)
        List<LicenseInfo> licensesList = new List<LicenseInfo>();

        //concat zip the three lists with a comma-separated for each entry in the new list with this pattern ("License Type, Total Count, Consumed Count"). 
        //Example("Entrprise License,200,50")
        List<string> licensesConcatenatedList = licenseTypeArray.Zip(totalLicenseArray.Zip(consumedLicenseArray, 
            (x, y) => x +","+ y), 
            (x1,y1) => x1 + "," + y1).ToList();

        
        licensesConcatenatedList.ForEach(t => licensesList.Add(new LicenseInfo
        {
            LicenseType = t.Split(new char[] { ',' })[0],
            TotalLicenesesCount = int.Parse(t.Split(new char[] { ',' })[1]),
            ConsumedLicensesCount = int.Parse(t.Split(new char[] { ',' })[2])
        }));
```

Now you have your data in one list of entities that wrap all information you want to display in the gridview, then just bind this new list to the gridview as a data source as usual. You will use the names of the properties as the field names in your GridView.

Comment: I need to show three columns.  type of licenses.the total number of licenses, the total consumed licenses. How do I add these rows  together to a datagridview foreach value in the three arrays?

Comment: Thanks for this. I am getting an error though. It says input string not in correct format.

Comment: Sorry if i am wrong here, I am still learning c#. I have used the code below for the gridview:var source = new BindingSource();
            source.DataSource = licensesConcatenatedList;
            licenseDataGridView.DataSource = source;

Comment: Your data source in this case will be "licensesList", not "licensesConcatenatedList", Also what you need to do is like the following:   licenseDataGridView.DataSource = licensesList;                                                        licenseDataGridView.DataBind();

Comment: If you still have issues, you can ask me again. I did not test this code with samples of data, so you can try this code on your data and start tweaking it a little.